# How to us formatMessage on Redux Class Component

Tags: reactjs, intl

Trying to use "formatMessage" on class component.

But it doesnt work;

```
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl";
......
  render() {
    const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;
      return (
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="card-header flex-wrap border-0 pt-6 pb-0">
              <div class="card-title">
                <h3 class="card-label">{formatMessage({ id: "LOCATION.INDEX.TITLE" })}
                <span class="d-block text-muted pt-2 font-size-sm">light head and row separator</span></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <table ref="main" class="table table-striped- table-hover table-checkable" />
            </div>
          </div>);
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ auth }) => ({ authToken: auth.authToken }),
  auth.actions
)(DataTable);
```

And it returns

TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#injectintl-hoc).

You should wrap your component with `injectIntl`

```js
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl";
......
  render() {
    const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;
      return (
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="card-header flex-wrap border-0 pt-6 pb-0">
              <div class="card-title">
                <h3 class="card-label">{formatMessage({ id: "LOCATION.INDEX.TITLE" })}
                <span class="d-block text-muted pt-2 font-size-sm">light head and row separator</span></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <table ref="main" class="table table-striped- table-hover table-checkable" />
            </div>
          </div>);
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ auth }) => ({ authToken: auth.authToken }),
  auth.actions
)(injectIntl(DataTable)); // here we use injectIntl HOC
```